# Phaser - Create player object

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm following this tutorial, https://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/extending-sprite-demo-2, and I have the following:

```
MonsterBunny = function (game, x, y, rotateSpeed) {
    Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game, x, y);
    var test = game.add.sprite(x, y, 'player');
    test.rotateSpeed = rotateSpeed;
};
MonsterBunny.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
MonsterBunny.prototype.constructor = MonsterBunny;
MonsterBunny.prototype.update = function() {
    this.angle += this.rotateSpeed;
    console.log('a');
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create });

function preload() {
    game.load.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    game.load.image('player', 'http://examples.phaser.io/_site/images/prize-button.png');
}

function create() {
    var wabbit = new MonsterBunny(game, 0, 100, 1);
    var wabbit2 = new MonsterBunny(game, 150, 100, 0.5);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/602ccpL4/)

The sprites don't spin and the `update` function doesn't log to the console any more. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two bugs in your code.

First, in your `MonsterBunny` constructor you are adding 2 sprites not 1. The `var test = game.add.sprite..` shouldn't be there, because a sprite is already added by calling the sprite constructor [Phaser.Sprite.call](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Sprite.html).

Second, in the call to the `Phaser.Sprite` constructor you forgot to add the `key` parameter, so which image to use, in your case it's called `'player'`. Because of this, it actually adds a sprite but it doesn't display at all.

So, something like this should work:

```
MonsterBunny = function (game, x, y, rotateSpeed) {
    // call sprite constructor to create sprite
    Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game, x, y, 'player');

    // set extra variables
    this.rotateSpeed = rotateSpeed;
    this.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5); // for centered rotation

    // add sprite to game world
    game.add.existing(this);
};
```

Comment: But if do like that we only create one sprite. I modify example to create multi sprite in a Object

Comment: @BdR is correct with his code. Here's a corrected Fiddle that I did separately, so it doesn't include the `anchor` modification: https://jsfiddle.net/31odrwLz/